# require 'rspec/autorun' -- doesnt work for me

Tags: ruby, rspec

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
~/ruby_programs$ rspec --version
3.0.3

~/ruby_programs$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin10.0]



~/ruby_programs$ cat my_rspec.rb
require 'rspec/autorun'

describe "require 'rspec/autorun'" do
  it 'should not cause this program to throw an error' do
    true
  end

end

~/ruby_programs$ rspec my_rspec.rb 
.

Deprecation Warnings:

Requiring `rspec/autorun` when running RSpec via the `rspec` command is deprecated. Called from /Users/7stud/ruby_programs/my_rspec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'.


If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

1 deprecation warning total

Finished in 0.00159 seconds (files took 0.16241 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Here we go:

```
~/ruby_programs$ ruby my_rspec.rb
my_rspec.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method `describe' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `RSpec` is missed. You should do the following:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

RSpec.describe "require 'rspec/autorun'" do
  it 'should not cause this program to throw an error' do
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find a single example of a program using `require 'rspec/autorun'`!  The docs are terrible: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line ... All they say is: `when invoking ruby, ... add a
require 'rspec/autorun' to one or more of your spec files.`

Comment: @7stud When running with `rspec` command, call `describe` with `RSpec` and no need to require anything. So when running with `ruby`, just add a `require 'rspec/autorun'`.

Comment: I've never seen a single rspec test written as `RSpec.describe ...`. Given that, one can't just add `require rspec/autorun`.  The docs are remiss in not mentioning that.

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute the rspec using $ bundle exec rspec instead of rspec only